# Deduce how much does damping affect the angular frequency of a harmonic oscillator

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I am asked to deduce by how much does damping change the angular frequency of a harmonic system. I immediately thought to use the equation $\omega$ = $\sqrt{\omega_0^2 - \frac{\gamma^2}{4}}$. However, my lecturer told us to use this identity, $\sqrt{1+y}$ = 1 + $\frac{y}{2} - \frac{y^2}{8} + \frac{y^3}{16}$. I tried to factor out $\omega_0^2$ from the first equation to get the form $\sqrt{1+y}$ she would like, but this does not make sense to me as it seems to complicate a simple equation. Can anyone help me figure out if I am going down the right path or if there's a whole other concept I'm missing to which I can apply her identity?

Comment: pls show you effort to factor out $\omega_0$.

Comment: @JEB $\omega = \sqrt{\omega_0^2 (1- \frac{\gamma^2}{4\omega_0^2})} = \omega_0 \sqrt{1- \frac{\gamma^2}{4\omega_0^2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you factor out the $\omega_o^2$ you get $\omega$ = $\omega_o  \sqrt {1 - (\gamma ^2/\omega_o^2)/4}$. I cannot remember from my first year waves lecture but I think $\gamma ^2/\omega_o^2$ equals to some other important variable. Then you can use the Maclaurin series to simplify it out. Once you manage to do that, then get rid of all the ordered terms greater than and equal to 2. This should leave you with a simplified answer.

Comment: $\frac{\gamma^2}{\omega_0^2} = \frac{1}{Q^2}$ where Q is the quality factor. However, why would I want to eliminate the ordered terms greater than and equal to 2?

Comment: my result is $\frac{\omega}{\omega_0} = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4Q^2}}$.  if i let y = $-\frac{1}{4Q^2}$, then i can use the series. But my question still stands why do I eliminate the ordered terms greater than two ?

Comment: Suppose quality factor $Q$ = 2.  Then $\gamma ^2/\omega_o^2$ = $1/4$. The second order term of this is $1/16$ which is small compared to $1/4$ and so on, hence, you can choose to ignore it. This is a tool that is used very often in Physics and is very helpful for simplification etc.

Comment: Note, this only works if $\mid y \mid < 1 $

Comment: okay so following these steps i got  $\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}$ = $\sqrt{1+\frac{-1}{4Q^2}}$ = $1-\frac{1}{8Q^2}-\frac{1}{128Q^4}$+... And if i only choose the first two terms, I get $\frac{\omega}{\omega_0} \approx 1-\frac{1}{8Q^2}$. In the context of my questions, this yields $\frac{\omega}{\omega_0} \approx 1$. Which makes $\omega \approx \omega_0$. This would lead me to conclude that damping did not change the angular frequency by any significant amount?

Comment: Sound absolutely correct from your context! I am guessing $Q$ is a large number for you to make that assumption.

Comment: Yes it was huge but one question, why couldn't I have simply calculated it using the true formula with the square root, which instead a Maclaurin was suggested that is simply an approximation that would as i mentioned before complicate things ?

Comment: Good question! Suppose $y$ from the Maclaurin expansion was a smaller number. If you just used the equation inside the square root, your answer would be usual to 1. But when using the expansion up to the first order, you can get an answer of 1.000000001 etc. Sorry this is not a good example and I am sure you can look up some more stuff on it. You will see its use in your education when deriving equations and plenty of other stuff etc. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

$$ \omega = \omega_0\sqrt{1-\xi^2} $$

with:

$$ \xi = \frac c {2\sqrt{mk}} \equiv \frac 2 Q $$

where $c, k, m$ are the damping constant, spring constant, and inertia constant (aka: mass).

As pointed out, the radical is negative for $\xi > 1 $ ($Q<\frac 1 2$), this means you have an over damped oscillator that never oscillates.

The critical oscillator ($Q=\frac 1 2$) asymptotically approaches equilibrium. For any larger value, the oscillator is underdamped (see wikipedia figure).

[image]

For small $\xi$, or large quality factor $Q$, you can expand the radical:

$$ \sqrt{1-\frac 1 {4Q^2}} \approx 1 - \frac 1 {8Q^2} - \frac 1 {128Q^4}$$

You can drop the 2nd and higher term because the formula is a correction to the frequency, and at $Q=1/2$, it reads:

$$ 1 - \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 8 $$

but you don't even have a frequency..it's not oscillating, so a 12.5% error is not a concern.

The exact resonant frequency is of interest particularly when the oscillator is driven by a sinusoidal force with frequency $\omega$. In that case, the amplitude of the response is (as shown in the (wikipedia) figure):

$$ Z = \sqrt{(2\omega_0\xi)^2 + \frac{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2}{\omega^2}} $$

and it is here that you can justify the dropping of higher order terms. The width of the resonances is much greater than the 2nd order correction to the frequency.

[image]figure:

Moreover, in the real world oscillator where the frequency matters, $Q$ is big, $10^4$ to $10^6$ is common in quartz oscillators (so the 2nd order correction is $10^{-18}$ to $10^{-26}$).

This may also come up in mechanical systems, say positive aerodynamic feedback on an airplane control surface, or a bridge responding to wind. (This is a critical application: the resonance can destroy the structure). If the $Q$ factor is low, the system response to forcing is not very strong, and exists over a wide range of frequencies. If there is a high-Q resonance, then you need to now the frequency, but because it is high-Q, the 2nd order correction is negligible.